# jQuery POST to PHP appears in browser, but not the PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been pulling my hair out over this problem and I must have searched through over fifty other questions on here, to no avail. I'm trying to code a website using PHP, MariaDB, jQuery, and other web development technologies, however I've encountered issues trying to post variables from the client-side (with jQuery) to the server-side (PHP). I created a very simple file just to isolate the problem that I'm having:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
</head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: {'name': "name1"},
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["name"])){
        $i=$_POST["name"];
        echo "num: ".$i;
    }
    else{
        echo "No information supplied";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I refresh the page, and I constantly get the failure message "No information supplied". I know the POST is getting sent to the browser, because I can see it in Firebug, and its status code is 200 OK, so I know that I must be doing something correctly. Is my PHP syntax messed up? I know that this will work just fine when I'm pulling data from forms embedded in the regular HTML.

Thank you for your assistance, and I apologize in advance if this is a really simple problem. I'm trying to learn web development as well as possible. I feel like I've tried everything, down to using the longer .ajax way of sending a POST variable, rather than using .post().

Comment: php cant update the webpage once it's been sent. php works on the server, only js works on the browser. if you want php to display your message, submit the form like a regular form and get rid of the ajax.

Comment: Is this file also called `index.php` itself..?

Comment: Yes, the file is index.php.

Comment: Well, you're making 2 requests to the server then: 1st by opening the page in your browser (which renders the "No information supplied" part). Then the JS runs on the client side and requests the page again - fully discarding any information received though.

Comment: Could I use jQuery to send the data to a form, which will then send it to the PHP? Is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: As @Pamblam suggested: You should use a simple form (either in the index.php file itself or in another file and setting form `action` to the php file that handles the input).

Comment: In the original project, the issue I was having involved a jQuery method that would take the index of a table's (created from a database) row after clicking on a button, and allowing the user to edit that row. I was trying to push that variable to a method in the PHP that edits that row's entry in the database, but it doesn't accept anything from the jQuery. Is that an incorrect approach overall? I know that it's possible to create invisible forms that accept variables, would that be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer, you will be testing to see if there is an ajax request, if so process it, if not spit out your original page.  As for the ajax call we are adding a success callback that will then update your body tags with your returned. data

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
        if(isset($_POST["name"])){
            $i=$_POST["name"];
            echo "num: ".$i;
        }
        else{
            echo "No information supplied";
        }
        die;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
</head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: {'name': "name1"},
      success: function(data){
          $('body').html(data);
      }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
this is the original body content
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the problem stems from the PHP executing before the ajax does, causing my problem. So the solution in this situation is to make sure the ajax runs first whenever I need to do something like this, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code runs *before* you trigger the ajax request, because the server  interprets and runs PHP before you get to see the resulting HTML in the browser

What you need is add a `success` callback in the ajax request object which will get the result of ajax request and do something useful with it, such as place it into a `<div>` element. The example below simply displays it

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  data: {'name': "name1"},
  success: function(serverReponse){ alert(serverResponse) }
});
```